# AWS Lambda python function not able to MongoDB through VPC

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lambda, vpc

I have a Python Lambda function that's not able to connect to MongoDB (private IP) through a VPC.

I've ported out the part that's failing in the snippet below.

```
    import pymongo

    def handler(event, context):
      try:
        client = pymongo.MongoClient(host=['10.155.152.15:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, serverselectiontimeoutms=5)
      except pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError as err:
        print err
```

Result: 
`No servers found yet`

For the user role, it has this Policy attached: (AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole) and (AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole)
. I've even allowed (AmazonVPCFullAccess) just to see, but it didn't help.

I've selected the same VPC as what MongoDB server using, along with all of the subnets. 
Security Group is BasicLambda which allows all traffic.

This has worked for me yesterday but somehow it's not working anymore. It seems to be some kind of connection permission issues.

Comment: Is the security group of your MongoDB server allowing incoming connections from the BasicLambda security group?

Comment: Yes. it allows all TCP from port 0-65535 from 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: is your host in a private subnet?

Comment: Yes, the mongodb server is in private subnet. I can connect to it from other servers within that subnet. I've included this subnet (and all other subnets) to the lambda function - maybe I shouldn't include all subnets?

Comment: It's a bit puzzling. This was working yesterday and I can't seem to find anything wrong with. Is there a possibility that there are disruptions with AWS's backends? If so, where can I see status of such events?

Comment: I have two different subnets and have just tried and failed to connect to another mongodb (in different subnet, which is also included in the lambda function).